Finding satellite visibility with ephemeris state vectors instead of TLE
I have been using Python excellent skyfield module to compute Earth satellite events from a given point (ie. visibility—rise, culmination, and set, as well as associated azimuth and elevation). However, for various reasons, I have to move away from using the given satellites' TLEs to ephemeris/state vector data (x, y, z, vx, vy, vz), both past and predicted.
I am very new to using this kind of data instead of using TLE propagators (through skyfield) to find such events. What Python tools are available to do such analysis?

Where are you getting your state vectors?  Whoever supplies them should be able to tell you how they obtained them, which should include some details of how they were generated and how your source propagates them.

Check the Skyfield documentation, in particular the section labeled "build a satellite from orbital elements". This allows you to create SGP4 objects from raw elements.  You will need to look up conversions from state vectors to kep elements.  Please note that you could quickly get into accuracy issues due to osculating elements, so this is a road to be careful on unless you are looking for just very simple propagations.
